# Nginx issue while including nginx config from a shared library in angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I am working in dockerzing an angular app with a shared library. Angular app has an nginx config and shared library has an nginx config too which i am including in the main nginx config. This is how my docker file looks like

```
FROM <nodejs image> as build

USER root

WORKDIR /app

#

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/

RUN npm ci

COPY . /app/

RUN npm run build

#nginx web server
FROM <nginx image > nginx:latest

USER root

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-conf /etc/nginx/nginx-conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I am copying entire nginx-conf folder as it has nginx.conf, mime.types and static files

Now my Nginx.conf looks like this

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  include mime.types;

  index index.html index.htm;

  server {
    listen {{port}};
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;


    include /sharedlibrary-config/sharedlibrary-nginx.conf;  #This is the problem line 


    location / {
      
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      if ($uri ~ .*.html) {
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          expires 0;
      }
      if ($uri ~* \.(js|css)) {
          add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
          expires 1y;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this i am including /sharedlibrary-config/sharedlibrary-nginx.conf and sharedlibrary-nginx.conf is the nginx config of shared library which looks like this

```
location /sharedlibrary-config {
  try_files /sharedlibrary-config/sharedlibrary.dev.json =404;
}
```

The problem is when app is deployed , i am getting error as "*4 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/sharedlibrary-config/" is forbidden"

I tried many options found in web but not successful so far.
I tried adding chmod 777 to sharedlibrary-config but no luck. still facing the same
Requesting assistance from pros here. please help